# When I try to print result of the power function I always get 0

Tags: c, printing

I am begginner in C and when I try to write some code like that  :

```
printf("\n  Answer : %d \n", 12* pow(2,1));
```

I always get  Answer : 0 
But when I write as a float point number like this :

```
printf("\n  Answer : %f \n", 12* pow(2,1));
```

I get : Answer : 24.0000

Is there anyone know why this is happening ?
I mean why 0 in decimal printing  ? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>`, set yout compiler warnings as high as they will go, and mind the warnings!

Comment: Why the close votes? This is the sort of question with a defined answer that is a perfect fit for SO.

Comment: You might like to RTFM here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html (how often did I read this page, so even a beginner might do so?)

Comment: And btw. both printf-statements' conversion specifiers try to print "*decimals*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see is the result of [Undefined Behaviour](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior).

The type expected by `printf` and the type passed do not match.

The specifier `"%d"` must match a value of type `int`, but matches a value of type `double` you provided with your expression.

Anything can happen.

Answer (score 3):

Using wrong specifier invoke undefined behavior. Result can be either expected or unexpected. `%d` is used for `int` type.

#### C11: 7.21.6 (p9):

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>282)</sup> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

`pow` returns `double` type. Its signature is

```
double pow(double x, double y);
```

Therefore you need `%f` to print `double` type.