# Why does the second unsigned long long int print a different value?

Tags: c

```
unsigned long long int a,b;
a=3;
b=2;
printf("%d %d",a,b);
```

Output:

```
3 0
```

Can someone please explain why `b` is printed as 0?

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28798520/3933332

Answer (score 6):

Using the wrong format specifier in `printf` leads to [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Use for signed:

```
printf("%lld %lld",a,b);
```

for unsigned

```
printf("%llu %llu",a,b);
```